# How to change the color for navigation drawer arrows on Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

my request is "How to change the color for navigation drawer arrows
The highlights on the navigation drawer arrows is white color, how can I change it to something different,color but let as still white colors only ..

If any possibility are there ? change navigation drawer arrows

Image on navigation drawer arrows:
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxyfd_dUtvCwczZWaGw3X2I2NVU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In your style.xml ,write this code.

<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    </style>
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">here give the colour code you want to</item>
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: @vpvel25-Thank u..happy coding..:)

Comment: This changes the color of the hamburger, but not the arrow.. (at least for me)